# How to remove the Content-Length header key before submitting GET call

Tags: karate

I have a requirement where for GET call Content-Length header key need to remove. If I submit the GET Request, getting Internal server error. Content-Length header key seems be adding by default while submitting the request. How we can restrict the header key

I have tried passing with only required headers but after submitting the request the request header section showing with the Content-Length header key which no where we have passed at framework level.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following 2 lines in Karate 1.4.0

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* method get
```

Result:

```
1 > GET https://httpbin.org/anything
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.6)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

There is no `Content-Length` header being set. So there is something strange going on for you. Maybe you have supplied a body using the `request` keyword by mistake.

If you are still stuck, I think the best option is that you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue